# How do I get the Jenkins current job so I can update it's number?

Tags: jenkins, jobs

I'm using the following to update the build number of my job in Jenkins:

```
def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName("Petes Build Test")
job.nextBuildNumber = build_number
job.save()
```

Is there a way to get the same job - instead of by name - but the current job. I'm only interested in updating the job number.

I can go through each job and use their name but it would be simpler to use the 'current job' if I knew how to get that.

Comment: Dont think so, but you could use the exposed environment variable JOB_NAME (access with `env.JOB_NAME`)  instead of hardcoding the current name.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!